# Desktop Launcher doesn't start my app, while terminal does

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, launcher, shortcut-file

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, I've created launchers for different applications but one of the launchers doesn't start my app, I don't know why, but when I run the same command in the terminal it works properly.
The structure of the files `.desktop` is the same

Here's my launcher `designer.desktop` file which doesn't work

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=TIBCO Designer
Exec=/TIBCO/tibco/designer/5.11/bin/designer
Icon=/TIBCO/tibco/tools/resouces/icons/tibco-icon.png
```

and this is the one working `dbvis.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=DbVisualizer
Exec=/opt/DbVisualizer/dbvis
Icon=/opt/DbVisualizer/resources/images/ix3/dbvis-icon.icns
```

both of them have permissions to be executed `chmod +x *.desktop`

[image: screenshot showing files permissions]

When I run this command `/TIBCO/tibco/designer/5.11/bin/designer` in my terminal it works fine and my application starts successfully

Comment: I feel this may be a better fit for https://askubuntu.com/, especially since it concerns third-party software only

Comment: @Moira Thank you ! I'm gonna post it there